# How to use background-size: contain on element with responsive height

Tags: html, css

I'm using background-size: contain on a div, but realized although the image is responsive, the div element height remains fixed. What is a good solution that allows the div's height to respond just as the image so I do not get white space between the div and it's lower sibling element?

```css
    .projectBlurbHero {
        background-image: url('http://artofabsence.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/camel-ride1.jpg');
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: top center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 460px;
        max-height: 460px;
    }
```

```html
    <div>
       <div class="projectBlurbHero"></div>
       <div class="projectBlurbTitle">
          <h2>Title</h2>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I see no point of doing this as a background image, why not just use image as that is the behaviour you are after?

Comment: Content will later go into the div. This is just for example sake.

Comment: There is two option of doing it 
#1 use media query to handle the height in every screen
#2 using the % but to use it you must have content inside that div.

Comment: I know enough to know that if this is going to work, it will need javascript, or  you'll need to make some compromises on content flow inside the element with the background. meaning absolute positioning and the like.

Comment: I don't get it, are you not gone use the image or is the `projectBlurbHero` gone contain content?

Comment: @Dejan.S yes, projectBlurbHero will contain content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your goal is to have the div maintain its aspect ratio (so that if the width is forced to decrease, the height will decrease as well so that the image scales proportionately without white space), you are probably going to have to do calculations to get the height of the div.  For that, you can use JavaScript, or the calc feature of css (though the latter is not universally supported; Opera Mini doesn't accept it).  You can also use media queries to set breakpoints and prevent the whitespace from being too high, though cases where that would be the best choice are rare.

One exception: If the width scales directly to the width of the browser window, you can use the vw unit, though Opera Mini doesn't support that one either.

If it's supposed to respond to something else, that may or may not allow for an easier approach, depending on what it's responding to.

Comment: I'm not worried about Opera Mini. Using vw works exactly like I wanted. Thanks!